# Connect To Teradata in ssms

Tags: azure, ssms, teradata

I have a table in Teradata Db which I need to compare with table in Azure , I am planning to connect both the servers in ssms and then compare them at single place using query , I am able to connect Azure Db in ssms , but not able to connect Teradata in ssms. please help me to connect to teradata DB in ssms. How can I do that ??

Comment: You'll need to install the vendor's ODBC or .NET driver. If you have difficulty pleas post a new question clearly showing what you have tried and the problem you are encountering.

Comment: I have Teradata SQL assistant 15.0.0, so When I tried downloading Teradata ODBC then it was uninstalling the existing utilities , including TD SQL assistant . So I gave up that option. I found few solutions where people tried creating linked server in ssms and connect to Teradata Server. But using those solutions I am not able to connect to Teradata , May be there is something which I am missing. So can you please help

Comment: I know the IP address of My TD prod server

Comment: TTU 17+ does not include SQL Assistant. I believe TTU 16.20 is still available if you want to upgrade and keep SQL Assistant. Or If you had SQL Assistant 15.10.01 or later installed you could install a newer version of other TTU alongside and keep the old as well. Note that SQL Assistant uses 32-bit ODBC (or a .NET provider) while SSMS needs 64-bit ODBC.